# How can I compile my application for iOS on Mac Tiger with NeoMAD?

Tags: ios, macos, mobile-application, osx-tiger, neomad

Running NeoMAD on iMac Tiger, I am not able to compile my application for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use NeoMAD on iMac, Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion" or later is required. This is because Xcode 4.2 is required to build applications for iPhone and Xcode 4.2 requires Mac OS X Lion. So you won't be able to compile for iPhone on Tiger. 
Note that you can not compile for Android either because the Android SDK requires Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later.